# How can I decode data from multiple nested dictionaries into an object?

Tags: python

When I decode a dictionary value, I cannot directly access the attributes by properties. It throws an error because the data in the b.data array is a dictionary.

In GoLang, I just need to define it like that, and it will automatically map to an object instead of a dictionary

```
from typing import List


class A:
    field_a: int
    field_b: str


class B:
    data: List[A]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)


data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "field_a": 1,
            "field_b": "a"
        }
    ]
}

b = B(**data)
print(b.data[0].field_a)
```

When I run the above code in Python 3.11, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(b.data[0].field_a)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'field_a'
```

Comment: Just do `data[0]["field_a"]`. Or if you have actual behaviour to attach to that data you'll have to instantiate A (which should probably be a dataclass) somewhere. Note in 3.11 you don't need List, just use list[A].

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English. But can I ask one more question, for Python and in the above case, should I not use a class for nested dictionaries, right?

Comment: There's no point to either of the classes you've shown, but that might be because you've trimmed this down too far in your question. Just use the dictionaries and lists until you have _behaviour_ (methods, computed properties, ...) you need to add to the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the data from inside the object of class B, you can try something like-

```
print(b.data[0]["field_a"])
```